# Can't run Gitlab CI for specific tag using regex

Tags: regex, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run the Gitlab CI only for commits whose tags match a certain pattern (v0.4.3 or v0.7.9.0), but it never seems to match. How could I accomplish this?

```
stage: deploy
only:
  - master
only:
  - tags
only:
  - /^v[0-9](?:\.[0-9]){2,3}
```

Comment: I think you're just missing the trailing forward slash

Comment: Where in the string?

Comment: Trailing, so, at the end of it

Comment: It turned to be that the problem. I'm not familiar with the platform, can I mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: Cool, i'll just write it as an answer in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an issue with syntax. Your pattern is missing a trailing forward slash.

`/^v[0-9](?:\.[0-9]){2,3}/`